# Change value of my own type while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

When I am debugging code in Visual Studio, I can change values of variables by clicking on the overlay that pops up when I hover over my variable of choice. The label which displays the value turns into a text box and I can enter a new value which gets assigned as soon as I hit enter.

What do I have to implement in my own types in order to support this kind of workflow? Currently Visual Studio shouts at me that there is no implicit conversion from string to my type. If I add such an implicit operator it works fine, but is there another way of achieving the same without having to add the implicit conversion to my type (well, I could mark the conversion as `[Obsolete]`so that nobody can call it from code - but that's not the cleanest way I guess) just like `[DebuggerDisplay]` can achieve to display something else while debugging while leaving `ToString()` independent to whatever business logic demands?

Comment: Debugging like this is really last-resort type stuff, how often do you really need to do this?

Comment: If there were a mechanism that required only one attribute to say which function to call in order to do the conversion, then why not use it...

Answer (score 1):

> > The label which displays the value turns into a text box and I can enter a new value which gets assigned as soon as I hit enter.

The workaround you show is the Data ToolTips in the code editor, it is the usual way we edit the value during VS debugging.

Other workarounds I know is that：

(1) Custom the debugging view with the natvis extension.

For example, you could create a type visualizer for a custom data type like the sample in following blog:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2012/07/12/debugger-type-visualizers-for-c-in-visual-studio-2012/

(2) Use certain debugging window like Watch windows or others, but my understanding it is not convenient, I mean that use the ToolTips(the way you provide) would be better.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa6fy2x5(v=vs.120).aspx

Hope it could provide useful information or a path.

Comment: The link you provided under (1) relates to C++. Is the approach also applicable to C#?

Comment: @David, good question. we can’t load the .natvis file from the C# projects, it really has a limitation. But we can write a Visualizer in C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164759.aspx. Other members also asked the similar issue before with the workaround just using the DebuggerTypeProxy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764714/how-to-use-visual-studio-text-visualizer-for-custom-types. Not found other better workaround.

Comment: @David, what about this issue? Whether you could get useful information from my previous suggestions? Any update, feel free share it here:)