# How to show the text visualizer for custom classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have builder class that generates a string. The output string is available through the `ToString()` method. I want to show this output in visual studio's debugger.

When I take a look at the raw string I get the following result:

[image: string]

When I look at the builder however it is missing the newlines as well as the "View" button:

[image: MethodScriptBuilder]

Adding `[DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]` to the at least shows the newlines, but still doesn't have the "View" button.

[image: MethodScriptBuilder]

How can I make my class automatically display itself exactly like the string, including the "View" button?

Comment: Given that MethodScriptBuilder is a property of wherever you are debugging now, can't you just open up MethodScriptBuilder and view the property containing this string? That will give you the "View" button on the property. Or did you want to specifically have this as a feature of MethodScriptBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to add a [DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute?view=net-6.0) to your builder class. It's not very pretty but it sounds like that is what you need.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764714/how-to-use-visual-studio-text-visualizer-for-custom-types) is another SO-question to look at.

Comment: But which proxy?